# CRAM-MD5 Implementation

Tags: encryption, passwords, smtp, imap

I'm looking at implementing CRAM-MD5 authentication for an IMAP and SMTP server. Problem is that CRAM seems to require a clear text password to be available at all times. The server sends the client a unique challenge and the client returns:

```
MD5( MD5(password, challenge), MD5( password ) )
```

I can't see a way to check this without having a clear text password, the specification doesn't say it **has** to have one available but it only seems logical.

The only solution I can come up with is to encrypt (properly encrypt, not hash) the password into the database (probably using RSA key based AES, as I already have something to deal with that) and decrypt it when I need to compare, seems a very slow way around though as it will need decrypting and hashing for every single login on SMTP and IMAP.

Is this the best solution / most efficient solution?

Or, better, is CRAM out-of-date now because even less secure authentication over the wire is secured with SSL now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the trick is that all you really need is the unfinalized md5 of the password which is the same as the intermediate state of the md5 context before finalizing.

```
MD5_CTX ctx;
MD5Init(&ctx);
MD5Update(&ctx, password, length);
```

if you do this and then store the value of `ctx` as `hashed`, then one can then use copies of it in CRAM MD5 like this

for `MD5(password, challenge)`

```
MD5Update(&hashed, challenge, length);
MD5Final(&digest, &hashed);
```

and for `MD5( password )`

```
MD5Final(&digest, &hashed);
```

the rest of `MD5( MD5(password, challenge), MD5( password ) )` is rather simple

i would have liked to use python for this example but in the standard md5 there is no way to get access to the state of a md5 object so i used libmd5's api

Comment: Wish you had written it in python, that's what I'm writing this in :p. 
That seems to be the best solution. Keeps the password somewhat secure (as far as MD5 can be anyway). So I might use my idea of encrypting it anyway and then still be able to provide CRAM MD5 functionality.

Comment: This may be better than storing the password in plain text in that users using the same password in multiple places may be less affected, but the db still contains everything you'd need for a log-in. Which is hard to avoid for CRAM.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a draft RFC proposing to move DIGEST-MD5 to historical status, CRAM MD5 isn't in a much better state either.

If you want proper security, start with TLS and SASL - in that mode, PLAIN is considered acceptable, but, if as far as you're concerned it's not satisfactory, then I would recommend implementing GSSAPI or NTLM on top of it.

Comment: Thanks, the RFC status helps my understanding a lot. I was struggling to see the point of CRAM MD5 these days as TLS with simpler protocol looked a lot better. I'm keen not to add another layer between the database and the program though because it's not meant to be abstracted at all so GSSAPI or NTLM aren't really options.

Comment: I hope you're planning to write your own e-mail client too then ;)

Comment: Why so? Do GSSAPI and NTLM provide client authentication? From the brief look, I gathered they were server-side auth mechanisms.

Comment: About the only protocols I know of supported by RFC compliant e-mail clients are CRAM, DIGEST, NTLM, GSSAPI, PLAIN and Login.

Comment: I'll look into some figures on NTLM and GSSAPI usage to see whether to implement them as I've honestly never heard of them. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

The sources for Python of [hashlib.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e8da570d29a8/Lib/hashlib.py) say that you can initialize a hash instance with binary data but from the usage it seems to mean "initialize with the hash of this data".

However, you can clone the object with it's internal state intact, so you could pickle the object and store that in lieu of the password. To get the password MD5, unpickle the object, and to get the challenge hash, unpickle it and call it's update() method with the challenge data.

Comment: But this can then be unpickled by anyone and used surely? If the code has access to the clear text state to be able to update the hash then surely it can still be found.

I appreciate this is still fairly good in terms of obfuscation because it will take some doing to realise what it is and how to undo it. But I think I'm going to run with fully encrypting it into the DB.

Comment: Without checking the source, I would assume that the object only retains the current hash since you don't need to retain the plaintext - which would be the initialization vector you'd want as referenced in the accepted answer above.